# In django, django rest framework : User matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I copied https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fh-drf-friendship/0.1.1 (Because i don't know how to apply fh-drf-friendship on my project.)

**views.py**

```
class FriendViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['to_user'] = self.get_parents_query_dict()['user']
        serializer = FriendSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            serializer = FriendReadSerializer(instance)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get_object(self):
        to_user = User.objects.get(pk=self.get_parents_query_dict().get('user'))
        from_user = User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Friend.objects.get(to_user=to_user, from_user=from_user)
```

**serializers.py**

```
   class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        related_postwriter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
        related_commentwriter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'related_postwriter', 'related_commentwriter')


    class FriendSerializer(rest_framework_common.serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='from_user', queryset=User.objects.all())

        class Meta:
            model = Friend
            exclude = ('url', 'from_user',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            fr = FriendshipRequest.objects.get(from_user=validated_data['from_user'], to_user=validated_data['to_user'])

            if fr and fr.accept():
                return Friend.objects.get(from_user=validated_data['from_user'], to_user=validated_data['to_user'])


    class FriendReadSerializer(rest_framework_common.serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user = UserSerializer(source='from_user')
        created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(source='created')

        class Meta:
            model = Friend
            exclude = ('url', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'created',)
```

django version == 1.9.7

django rest framework version == 3.4.1

python3 == 3.5

On `urls.py`, there are `router.register(r'friend', views.FriendViewSet, base_name='friend')`

And when i go `http://127.0.0.1:8000/friend/` on web browser,

`DoesNotExist at /friend/
User matching query does not exist.` comes.

How can i solve it?

Comment: most probably the problem is inside `get_object` method in which you are trying to retrieve `User` objects. Your criteria by which you are trying to filter users might be incorrect

Comment: Don't give up and try to use some kind of debugger e.g. `wdb`